how to exclude patents from a specific country?
There is an inventor with my same name, and I am setting up an external search using USPTO and I would like to exclude the patents based on a specific country or for instance when the author zip code is listed as N/A.
Any help on examples for setting up more complex external searches is greatly appreciated
Regards
Luca

Does this have to be at the USPTO? It’s pretty easy at Lens. https://www.lens.org/

Patents have inventors not authors. If qualifying on the city of residence of an inventor is required the USPTO might be unique in offering that field.

When you say based on a specific country do you mean patents issued by a specific country?

thanks, for the reply. Yes I was looking to exclude inventor from Italy. There is a flag such as IT.inco that can be used. I also tried as syntax [..] AND ("US".inco. NOT "IT".inco.) as way to include inventor from US but not Italy.. that did not seem to work.

Thanks for the details - you should edit the information into your question.

I formulated three search strings for patents with “computer” in the spec.
One unqualified, one qualified on having Italian inventors and one qualified on not having an Italian inventors.
Below are the strings and the number of hits, respectively
computer.spec.
5383531
computer.spec. AND it.inco.
28237
computer.spec. NOT it.inco.
5355294
While it isn’t perfect, the sum of “with Italians” and “without Italians” about add up to the unqualified search.

Thanks that worked

If there is an answer you like you can accept it. That is one way the SE reputation system awards points.
